# Java C++ code conversion

Tags: java, c++, porting

I need to convert this code (in C++) into Java code :

```
    short i;
    short j;
    short k;
    short result;
    unsigned short  m_table[ 256 ]

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++ )
    {
        k = i << 8;
        result = 0;
        for ( j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++ )
        {
            if ( ( result^ k ) & 0x8000 )   
                result= ( result<< 1 ) ^ 0x1021;
            else
                result<<= 1;
            k <<= 1;
        }
        m_table[ i ] = (unsigned short) result;
    }
```

...but I never get the same result...

My Java code is:

```
int i;
int j;
int k;
int result;
int m_table[ 256 ] = new int[256];

for ( i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++ ) {
    k = (i << 8);

    result = 0;

    for ( j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++ ) {

        if ( (( result^ k ) & 0x8000) != 0)
            result= (( result<< 1 ) ^ 0x1021);
        else
            result<<= 1;

        k <<= 1;
    }

    m_table[ i ] = (result);
}
```

Comment: What is your current Java code? Can you paste that as well?

Comment: you're probably getting bit by the fact there is no such thing as an unsigned short in Java.

Comment: how can i convert a short into an unsigned short

Comment: Here's my Java code : 

        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
        int result;
        int  m_table[ 256 ] = new int[256];

        for ( i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++ )
        {
            k =  (i << 8);
            result = 0;
            for ( j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++ )
            {
                if ( (( result^ k ) & 0x8000) != 0) 
                    result=  (( result<< 1 ) ^ 0x1021);
                else
                    result<<= 1;
                k <<= 1;
            }
            m_table[ i ] =  (result);
        }

Comment: And if you edited that code into your question, it'd be readable as well. ;)

Comment: That actually looks like C code, not C++, to me.

Answer (score 5):

You need to be careful in Java with bit operations. Java does not have any unsigned types, so you probably need to go one type size bigger than what you would use with the unsigned variety.

Comment: That's a good point. In this case, `unsigned short` should probably be replaced with `int`. Other than that, I think that C++ is all valid Java.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, upping the size of m_table is a solution.  However, you will need to be careful in the casting to keep it unsigned.

Simply doing:

```
m_table[ i ] = (int)result;
```

...for example, will carry over the sign bit of result.  So if the signed short result was -1 then m_table[i] will end up with -1 when what you really want is 0xffff.

Fix that with:

```
m_table[ i ] = result & 0xffff;
```

That should give you the equivalent of the original signed short to unsigned short cast... storing it in an int just to maintain the unsigned-ness.

Answer (score 1):

Is the JVM big-endian? What happens if you use the constants 0x0080 and 0x2110?

Comment: A discussion on the endianness of the JVM: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t548186-endianness-of-java-virtual-machine.html

Comment: @Thomas: A simple "yes" or "no" would suffice. ;)

Comment: I think the discussion was linked instead of an answer since the question is a bit of a loaded one in the case of Java.

Answer (score 1):

Java does integer operations on `int`s or `long`s (if present), so you'll need to case the results back to `short`. Also there is no automatic conversion from integers to booleans. Leaving out braces is a bit taboo. So:

```
        if ( ( result^ k ) & 0x8000 )   
            result= ( result<< 1 ) ^ 0x1021;
        else
            result<<= 1;
```

Should become:

```
        if (((result^k) & 0x8000) == 0) {
            result <<= 1;
        } else {
            result = (short)((result<<1) ^ 0x1021);
        }
```

The `unsigned` from `unsigned short` should go (no almost unsigned in Java, although you could use `char`). Java has the advantage of having reliable ranges and behaviour of integer types. Stick to using `short` if you mean 16-bits. The top 16-bits will be removed, but careful when reading out to `& 0xffff`. The original C (or "C++") code is not portable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have I believe is with left shifting( **<<** ) `int` values out of `unsigned short` range.  To remedy the problem you need to mask the result of left shift into the range.  The mask to use is 0xFFFF.  The thing to remember is that `&` is a very low precedence operator, so parenthesis (a lot of them) are in order.
Here is the modified example.

```
    final int m_table[ ] = new int[256];

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++ ) {
        // OK not to mask the result of << here, we are in unsigned short range
        int k = (i << 8); // BTW, terrible name for this variable

        int result = 0;

        for ( int j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++ ) {

            if ( (( result^ k ) & 0x8000) != 0)
            {
                result= (( (result<< 1) & 0xFFFF ) ^ 0x1021);
            }
            else
            {
                result <<= 1;     // Change to 1-liner if you wish
                result &= 0xFFFF; //
            }

            k <<= 1;     // Change to 1-liner if you wish
            k &= 0xFFFF; //
        }

        m_table[ i ] = result;
    }
```